# While running my RestAPI request I am getting headers required error

Tags: rest, jmeter, http-headers

I am hitting my rest API in JMeter with 3 user ramp-up time is 5 second and in the HTTP header manager but in the response in View result tree I am getting error -

> "errors":[{"id":"G_6143e7ac:15751914d3d:-7dff","level":"ERROR","type":"VALIDATION","message":"Invalid or incomplete PR4 header:\nRequired header Accept missing. \n"}]}

[image]

I am using headers as in the imag., Please help me if anything is missing here.

Comment: I dont think you are. The "Accept" header is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response clearly states that your request is missing [Accept](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header.

It may also be worth moving HTTP Header Manager under HTTP Request sampler (as a child) to limit its scope only to parent just in case you need to send different headers for different requests. See [Using JMeter's HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) article for details on manipulating request headers in JMeter tests

Comment: Hi, I have tried as per you suggested but now I am getting error -      {"errors":[{"id":"G_fcb37d6:15774ee2c3c:-7cd3","level":"FATAL","type":"TECHNICAL","message":"Could not find acceptable representation"}]}

Comment: This is something related to your application, contact application developers